# Classifying building walls from LiDAR point cloud

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, lidar, classification, las

I am currently working on mobile point clouds in order to extract 3D building models in the residential area. I could successfully classify ground, vegetation and building roof lines, but still have an issue with classifying building walls. The walls are not even classified as vegetation, they are still remained as unclassified. I could probably create 3D building from the roof lines by giving height values, but I want to get the entire building points including walls to create multipatch if I could.

I used FME (LAStools) and ArcGIS in classification process as well as viewing and analysis.

Comment: Could clarify what steps did take to classify points as ground, vegetation and building roof? What was the workflow? What tools and parameterization did you use? It might help letting us know what you already did and tried, so future readers can suggest improvements in the workflow and/or discard options you already tried.

Comment: A [Google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=algorithm%20for%20wall%20classification%20with%20lidar%20data) research throwed some articles related to this subject, but the question in its current form is a little bit broad, in my opinion.

Comment: That is, or I'm told it should be, fairly straightforward with FME. 

Use the PointCloudCoercer transformer and HullReplacer transformer in concave mode and this will give you the roofs as polygons. 

With these polygons clip the point cloud, and with the PointCloudExpressionEvaluator set the class component to whatever is inside the roof polygons, but does not have class yet (that is, not roofs, hence - walls).

Hope that helps. You can also ask this question on the FME knowledgecentre Q+A pages if you like: https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/index.html

Comment: @Mark Ireland, perhaps you can cast a reopen vote on this question and expand your comment into an answer. Let me know if you decide to do it, and I'll cast a reopen vote too. Thanks.